# Reset remembered firefox canvas decisions

Tags: firefox, canvas

Firefox 58 introduced a new feature, asking the user if we wants to allow HTML5 canvas image data for a website:

> Will you allow [website] to use your HTML5 canvas image data? This may
>   be used to uniquely identify your computer.

You can allow or deny the access, and you can **always remember** the decision.

How can I reset the decision once I have "always remembered" it (preferably individually for each website)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the `permissions.sqlite` sqlite database in your [Mozilla profile folder](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox), and then proceed to

`SELECT * FROM moz_perms WHERE type = 'canvas/extractData';`

From there you can decide which rows to keep or to delete with simple SQL `delete` statements, such as

```
DELETE FROM moz_perms WHERE type = 'canvas/extractData' AND origin = '<YOURSITEHERE>'
```

or of course via its id

```
DELETE FROM moz_perms WHERE type = 'canvas/extractData' AND id = <YOURID>
```

Please be careful when manipulating Firefox data, and be sure to backup your profile first.