# How can I block HTML Canvas fingerprinting in Firefox via permissions?

Tags: firefox, permissions, privacy, fingerprint, canvas

I ran a [Canvas fingerprinting browser test](https://browserleaks.com/canvas) and noticed that I am susceptible to Canvas fingerprinting in Firefox 66. This was a surprise to me, as I had read several [announcements](https://blogs.systweak.com/all-about-firefox-58-and-canvas-browser-fingerprinting/) declaring that Firefox 58 introduced a prompt when sites attempt to read Canvas Fingerprint data. Has this feature been removed?

#### How can I change Firefox settings so that it will prompt me to request permission before providing read access to the HTML Canvas?

I see several Firefox addons which can impede Canvas fingerprinting. [CanvasBlocker](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/canvasblocker/) alters the Javascript APIs. [Canvas Defender](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/no-canvas-fingerprinting/) adds some random noise to prevent an enduring fingerprint. However, I would rather change a permission to *prevent* code from being run, rather than installing an addon which will run *additional* code.

[This Superuser answer](https://superuser.com/a/1288817/499711) describes how Firefox stores site-specific Canvas permissions settings, and may be helpful. However, I am interested in changing the permission for *all* websites.

Comment: `Uniqueness: 100% (0 of 425093 user agents have the same signature)` - Is this good or bad..?

Comment: @DxTx. It means you are 100% unique, no other browser tested has the same identifiers as you, and so you can be tracked without being confused with anyone else.

Comment: Awesome. I have installed CanvasBlocker and still, I'm 100% unique. So, the addon doesn't seem to be working, then. (Also, tried with Canvas Defender. Same result). You can disable `privacy.resistFingerprinting`. But if you do, there are some issues that you have to face. For example, the Firefox browser won't start in full size. Some addon doesn't work, etc.

Comment: @DxTx That is not how those are supposed to work. In the default setting, CanvasBlocker (and, presumably, Canvas Defender) will spoof a new fingerprint every time a page loads. This means that you can be identified as a unique visitor, but not tracked across multiple visits, because your fingerprint will be unique _each time_.

Comment: @DxTx: Entropy0 is right. It's not uniqueness that's the problem so much as persistent uniqueness. It's okay to be a the only person on the block in a tiger suit as long as you don't wear the same tiger suit next time you return.

Comment: @Entropy0, That makes sense. Anyway, Is there a way to test it that it's, in fact, working as planned? If addon generating some general signature, then that's okay. But if it's generating a 100% unique signature (every time), then that's an also a problem, right? I mean, small sites might be able to track me.

Comment: @DxTx: For [other fingerprinting values](https://panopticlick.eff.org/), a completely unique identifier might be unusual, but for HTML Canvas, it's expected. That's why Canvas is so useful for fingerprinting.

Comment: @DxTx You can check whether you get a new hash upon reloading [this page](https://canvasblocker.kkapsner.de/test/test.html). And no, not even small sites can track you - you will look like a new user upon each site load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setting you are looking for is `privacy.resistFingerprinting`.

Though be aware that setting this to `true` also renders some websites that heavily utilize the canvas defunct (in my experience this mainly affects browser games, but YMMV). If you run into any trouble with this, [CanvasBlocker](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/canvasblocker/) set to block mode "fake" is probably your best bet.

Comment: After 2 months, I've decided to disable [`privacy.resistFingerprinting`](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Fingerprinting). It hasn't broken anything, but having the [wrong time zone](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1364261) is too annoying to me. The time zone is even used for browser history. See [other user's experience](https://shaunc.com/blog/article/firefoxs-privacy.resistfingerprinting-option-reports-a-very-old-useragent-50.0~9hsWyajkh6N2) with `privacy.resistFingerprinting`

Comment: I have disable it immediately. Wrong windows size is also some sort of trash.